# Can JSON be used as main stream database or data storage?

Tags: json, xml, database

Although Json seems lighter than xml, and can be used as small scale data holder, can it be used to hold heavier data assuming a million records, what are the limitations?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem as with XML: it's a linear format that needs to be parsed from start-to-end to do anything with it. So if you use JSON (or XML) for long-term storage, the access time to get one record is going to increase proportionately to the number of records in the data store.

And the solution is the same as with XML: use a database. Just as there are XML databases that reflect the original XML data model, there are also JSON databases. (However, simply dumping your data in a database "as is" might not be the best representation; you may want to do some normalization.)